# What is a "Promotional Version" of MS Office 2013?

Tags: license, microsoft-office-2013

I purchased a "Product Key" version of MS Office 2013. It arrived in a shrink wrapped box but I'm concerned with a sticker on the back (on the outside of the shrink wrap) which says:

> Promotional Version Upgrade Included

The box looks genuine, but I could not find anything online about "Promotional" versions of Office.

What are promotional versions, and will this software continue to work without having to pay for an upgrade?

[image: box front]
[image: box back]

Comment: It's probably an offer which is no longer available offering a cheap upgrade to Office 2016.

Comment: @DavidPostill - Thanks, I don't need to upgrade to 2016, I bought this version because I wanted Access. So if you are correct I should be ok. I've not opened the shrink wrap yet because I wanted to see if anyone knew more about Promotional versions, in case I have to send it back.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience,
a "promotional version" is not intended for resale to the general public.

Microsoft's advertising department may give such a free full copy of Office
in a seminar or similar, which
will typically have the "promotional version" sticker on it.

As it is not for resale, paying to buy it is a violation of the license terms.
It is a full copy, so I don't know how Microsoft would figure out that you got it illegitimately, but if they ever did figure it out, however unlikely,
they would be within the license terms to disable the product key.